# What is a legitimate alternative to hot linking images?

Tags: html, angularjs, image, api, http-status-code-403

I'm teaching a group of students about web development, and we're currently learning AngularJS. An exercise I created for them requires them to get a resource from the free and open [pokeapi.co](http://pokeapi.co). One of the pieces of data they can get back from the API is the URL to a sprite (small image) of the pokemon itself.

In the past, we've just hot linked the url to that image directly into an `<img>` tag. In trying to debug a 403 Forbidden error just now, I read about how hot linking is a bad practice. This makes total sense to me, but I now have 2 questions:

1. If the API is providing a URL to this image, what am I supposed to do with this URL other than hot link it in my HTML? Am I expected to also write a server that can download that image, create a link to the path of the image and use that URL instead? Is there another, more accepted way to avoid hot linking?
2. Isn't the purpose of the pokeapi to provide data for people to use? Why does it have restrictions that disable people's ability to use the data they're providing? I suppose that question goes hand-in-hand with my first one, because if there's an easy alternative to hot linking that I just haven't heard of, that may answer both of my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the API is providing a URL to this image, what am I supposed to do with this URL other than hot link it in my HTML?

This is explained in [the documentation](http://pokeapi.co/docsv2/):

*Locally cache resources and images when ever you request them.*

> Am I expected to also write a server that can download that image, create a link to the path of the image and use that URL instead?

Yes

> Why does it have restrictions that disable people's ability to use the data they're providing?

Because bandwidth isn't free and images use a significant amount of bandwidth.

Comment: So in an AngularJS-only application, how can I locally cache an image/resource if I'm getting a 403 forbidden on the image?

Comment: @bobbyz — You said it already: "write a server that can download that image, create a link to the path of the image and use that URL instead"

Comment: So "locally cache" actually means cache on the server, which ultimately will be remote... got it. I guess it means local in the sense that it is my own application and not someone else's, so I was confused. Thanks!